# XCode heapshots non-objects increases causing memory crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, heap-memory

I have an app running on iPAD.  Pretty complex one I would say.  The main issue I am facing now is the memory crash.  After going through several discussion threads, I could not figure out how to resolve it.

All my memory leaks are fixed.  While monitoring the heapshots in the instrument, they increase consistently of the order of 1 MB every cycle (I take heaphots at one normal "state" of the app).  80% of the heapshots increases are in "non-objects" category.  All of them have a reference count of 1.

Are these non-objects memory hogging a possible reason for my memory crashes?  Or is this only a symptom? Should I look for somewhere else for the root cause?  If these are probable cause, what is a systematic way of eleminating these memory hogs?

Edit: Added a screen shot.  As you can see, there is no call to my code (except the main() at the bottom). Can someone make any sense of the extended details on right side, where can I look for, to remove this 16 bits of memory (non-objects) having a ref count of 1 ?  This is just one instance, there are such thousands, causing my memory grow.

[image]

Comment: Apologies, my image could not be uploaded due to my low reputation in this forum :-) Shall add once I can.  I have been struggling with this issue for several weeks.  I promise to come back with my findings as I progress.

Comment: Here is an update on the issue.  I migrated the whole code to ARC.  It resolved a lot of issues.  To give the full picture, there was still some memory hogs happening.  When dig into more depth, I found out that one of my database functions was leaving the connection open (not closing it) and that was causing the memory hogging. Thanks to everybody for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess those are simple buffers allocated on the heap, as with `malloc()`.  For all of the ones which were allocated and not deallocated between two heapshots, examine the stack trace to see what caused the allocation.  If it's in your code, make sure you are freeing anything which you allocate like that.

By the way, not all memory management problems result in a true leak.  A true leak is an allocation that your code has lost the address to so it can not conceivably free it.  A pseudo-leak is where you still have a reference to the object, but your code is just never going to use it again.  That is, you've stashed it in some data structure somewhere where it will never be accessed again, when you really should have released it and forgotten about it.

So, you may be responsible for the non-object allocations because you are keeping objects around when you don't need to be.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.  In majority of the cases the stack traces  are not my code (library code I assume).  Really difficult to locate what causes it.  I can post a sample if it helps.

Comment: It looks like it's due to WebKit / a WebView. Are you using those?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I am using webview and when I remove the webview from the code, this non-objects are also coming down considerably.  I need webview in my app.  What might be causing it?  Anything I can look into further?  Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: I'm not sure. Is your app repeatedly loading new pages into the web view? Is it maintaining a history so that it could go back, even if your app never will allow that? Is the web page dynamic? Is it constantly loading new elements? Have you tracked down all of the objects which accumulate between heapshots and are you sure they should still be alive? (I mean, a single object could be maintaining a huge number of non-object allocations, so you have to be sure you're releasing everything you mean to be.)